# C++ How to use std::sort to sort a array of objects in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have the template class and array of pointers to objects and overloaded logic operators for my objects. My bubble sort is working. So it's know how to compare my objects
I want to replace it with standard sort 
Declaration

Implementation List.tem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
///////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <class Type>
List<Type>::List()
{
    itemPtr = NULL;
    used = 0;
    size = 0;
}


template <class Type>
List<Type>::List(const List<Type>& source)
{
    itemPtr = NULL;
    used = 0;
    size = source.size;
    itemPtr = new Type[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < source.used; i++)
        addItem(source.itemPtr[i]);
}

template <class Type>
List<Type>& List<Type>::operator = (const List<Type>& source)
{
    used = 0;
    if(this == &source)
        return(*this);  
    free();

    size = source.size;
    itemPtr = new Type[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < source.used; i++)
        addItem(source.itemPtr[i]);
    return(*this);
}    

template <class Type>
List<Type>::~List()
{
    free();
}

template <class Type>
void List<Type>::free() 
{
    if(itemPtr != NULL)
    {
        delete [] itemPtr;
        itemPtr = NULL;
    }
}

template <class Type>
void List<Type>::alloc(int sizeIcrease) 
{
    Type* tmpPtr = NULL;
    size += sizeIcrease;
    tmpPtr = new Type[size];
    copy(itemPtr, itemPtr+used, tmpPtr);
    free();
    itemPtr = tmpPtr;
}

template <class Type>
Type List<Type>::getItem(int index) const
{
    Type item;
    if(index >= 0 && index < used)
        item = itemPtr[index];
    return (item);
}    

template <class Type>
int List<Type>::findItem(Type itemIn)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < used; i++)
        if(itemPtr[i] == itemIn)
            break;
    if (i == used)  i = -1;
    return (i);
}

template <class Type>
void List<Type>::addItem(Type itemIn)
{
    if(used == size) alloc(10);
    itemPtr[used++] = itemIn;
    bubbles();
}

template <class Type>
void List<Type>::removeItem(Type itemIn)
{
    int index = findItem(itemIn);
    removeItem(index);
}

template <class Type>
void List<Type>::removeItem(int index)
{
    if(index >= 0 && index < used)
        itemPtr[index] = itemPtr[--used];
    bubbles();
}

template <class Type>
void List<Type>::readFile(Field fileName)
{
    Type itemTmp;   
    ifstream inFile(fileName.c_str());
    if(!inFile)
        cout << "Error opening file\n";
    do
    {
        inFile >> itemTmp;
        if(!inFile.fail())
            addItem(itemTmp);

    } while (!inFile.fail());
    //bubbles();
    vector<Type*> myvector; //(itemPtr, itemPtr+used);

    vector<Type>::iterator it;
    sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), sort_by_pointee<Type>());
    inFile.close();
}


template <class Type>
void List<Type>::writeFile(Field fileName)
{
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    if(!outFile)
        cout << "Error opening file\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < used; i++)
    {
        outFile << itemPtr[i] << "\n";
    }

    outFile.close();
}
    template <class Type>
void List<Type>::print()
{
//////Coded
}

template <class Type>
void List<Type>::bubbles()
{
////// Coded
}

template <class Type>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const List<Type>& ad)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ab.used; i++)    
        os << ab.getItem(i) << endl;
    return os;
}
template <class Type>
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ofs, const List<Type>& ad)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ab.used; i++)            
        ofs << ab.getItem(i) << ",";
    return ofs;
}

template<class Type>
struct sort_by_pointee 
{
    bool operator() (const Type* lhs, const Type* rhs) const
    {
        return (*lhs < *rhs);
    }
};
```

Comment: See http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/.

Comment: Or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort, which is better than the old, somewhat incorrect cpluplus.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the third argument to `std::sort()` is not provided, objects are sorted using `operator<` like:

```
if (a < b) {
   // ...
}
```

So all you need to sort objects of type `Foo` is to have either:

```
bool Foo::operator< (const Foo& rhs) const;
```

or

```
bool operator< (const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs);
```

---

That being said, if you have an array of *pointers*, then you will need to provide a custom predicate unless you want to sort objects by their memory address (I highly doubt this is what you want).  You can do something like:

```
template<class T>
struct sort_by_pointee {
    bool operator() (const T* lhs, const T* rhs) const
    {
        return (*lhs < *rhs);
    }
};
```

And use it like:

```
std::vector<Foo*> foos;
// ...
std::sort(foos.begin(), foos.end(), sort_by_pointee<Foo>());
```

---

**Edit**: the sample you posted will work fine and sort the data, but the vector does not act as a proxy for the data stored in the `itemPtr` array.  Read it again with my annotations:

```
{ 
    vector<Type> myvector (itemPtr, itemPtr+8);
    // 'myvector' holds a copy of the first 8 elements in the 'itemPtr' array.

    sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
    // contents of 'myvector' are sorted, but this is a copy of 'itemPtr''s
    // contents, so items in 'itemPtr' are still in their original order.
}
```

If you want to sort the contents of `[itemPtr,itemPtr+8)` in-place, you can just do:

```
std::sort(itemPtr, itemPtr+8); // use custom predicate if required.
```

---

**Edit**: OK, following the code you posted, I would fix the `readFile()` method from its original definition to:

```
template <class Type>
void List<Type>::readFile(Field path)
{
    ifstream file(path.c_str());
    if(!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error opening file\n";
    }
    for (Type item; file >> item;) {
        addItem(item);
    }
    sort (itemPtr, itemPtr+used);
}
```

Comment: Compiled, but still not sorted. I have my "bool operator<" overloading inside my object class. Is this a problem?

Comment: @user1290873: Perhaps it'd be easier if you posted a [minimal program that reproduces your problem](http://sscce.org/).  In particular, the class name, `operator<` declaration, the `std::vector<>` object and the call to `std::sort()` will be relevant.  If you don't mind posting your code as is, just make sure you strip it down so that we can focus on the important parts.

Comment: OK, let's try ...


template <class Type>
void List<Type>::addItem(Type itemIn)
{
 if(used == size)
  alloc(5);
 itemPtr[used++] = itemIn;
 //bubbles();
        vector<Type*> myvector;
        sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), sort_by_pointee<Type>());
}

template<class Type>
struct sort_by_pointee 
{
    bool operator() (const Type* lhs, const Type* rhs) const
    {
        return (*lhs < *rhs);
    }
};

Inside my object class

friend bool operator>(const Contact& c1, const Contact& c2);
friend bool operator<(const Contact& c1, const Contact& c2);

Comment: @user1290873: You can't format the code inside comments.  Edit your question to post the code.

Comment: @user1290873: There's a lot of code missing.  Also, the code you put in the comments sorts an empty vector of pointers.  Perhaps you should post more code, including the definition of your `List` class.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I posted implementation file. Do you need the definition file as well?

Comment: Tanks a lot! I'm ashamed it's what easy.

Comment: @user1290873: Don't be ashamed, everybody was a newbie once and still gets confused once in a while!  If this fixed your problem, make sure you [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234).